# Complex analysis, scalar product

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In the proof of Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, it is stated

Choose $\zeta \in \mathbf{C}$ such that $|\zeta|=1$ so that:
$<x,\zeta y>=|<x,y>|$ where $||$ is the standard norm in inn product spaces, $||x||=\sqrt{<x,x>}$.

Can someone explain me how is this possible? To choose such scalar, such that this equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume $\langle x,y \rangle \neq 0$, else it is obvious. Define
$$
\zeta:= \frac{|\langle x,y \rangle|}{\langle x,y \rangle}=\frac{\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}}{|\langle x,y \rangle|}.
$$
This is a complex numer with with $|\zeta|=1$.Then use the fact that the Sesquilinear form is $\mathbb{C}$-linear in its second argument to show your desired claim.

Comment: I think you made a typo. Vector of norm 1 is $\zeta = \frac{<x,y>}{|<x,y>|}$. Which when plugged in would yield $<x,y>*\overline{<x,y>}=|<x,y>|*|<x,y>|$ which leaves us with equality.  $|<x,y>|^{2}=|<x,y>|^{2}.$

Comment: No, if you use your vector you end up with $\frac{\langle x,y \rangle^2}{|\langle x,y \rangle|}$, which in general is a complex number divided by a real-valued number. I gave an alternate form of the expression in the edited answer, but you are missing a conjugate. The complex scalar product is usually taken to be $a \cdot b=\overline{a}b$, so it is $\mathbb{C}$-linear it its second argument.

Comment: Sorry to bother. But if I take my vector, wont it end up like this
$$<x,y\zeta>=|<x,y>|$$ then
$$\overline{\zeta}=\frac{\overline{<x,y>}}{\overline{|<x,y>|}}$$ now 
$$\overline{<x,y>}\cdot <x,y>=|<x,y>|\cdot \overline{|<x,y>|} $$
and since $a\cdot \overline{a}=|a|^{2}$ I get
$|<x,y>|^{2}=|<x,y>|^{2}$$ Sorry If I am wrong, I just want to learn.

Comment: Please state your precise definition of your scalar product. Is it $\mathbb{C}$ anti-linear or $\mathbb{C}$ linear in its second argument?

Comment: Linear in the first argument, and the following holds for the second argument, 
$$<x,\lambda y>=\overline{\lambda}<x,y>.$$

Comment: Okay, then we use a different convention. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form 
Yours is anti-linear in the second argument, while mine is linear in the second argument. If we use your convention, the vector you mentioned will do fine.